# Is there an age of retirement for teachers at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

We can see that Dumbledore is around 115 years old and would still have continued as the headmaster if he hadn't died, whereas Slughorn voluntarily retires at an age somewhere between **70** and **100**.

So is there an age at which a teacher *must* retire or do they just proceed to hold the position till they voluntarily retire or die?

Comment: [Death is not an excuse to stop teaching.](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Professor_Binns)

Comment: Ahh yes. Nearly forgot about this guy.

Answer (score 6):

## Teachers do retire but retirement doesn't seem to be mandatory.

There are examples of teachers retiring in the books. Professor Kettleburn, for example.

> "As to our second new appointment," Dumbledore continued, as the lukewarm applause for Professor Lupin died away, "well, I am sorry to tell you that Professor Kettleburn, our Care of Magical Creatures teacher, retired at the end of last year in order to enjoy more time with his remaining limbs."
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 5, The Dementor)*.</sub>

Or Professor Merrythought (who's retirement isn't quite confirmed - but it is speculated upon by a well-informed Voldemort).

> "Sir, is it true that Professor Merrythought is retiring?" Riddle asked.
>   "Tom, Tom, if I knew I couldn't tell you," said Slughorn, wagging a reproving, sugar-covered finger at Riddle, though ruining the effect slightly by winking. "I must say, I'd like to know where you get your information, boy; more knowledgeable than half the staff, you are."
>   <sub>*(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 17, A Sluggish Memory)*.</sub>

We also, as the question points out, have the example of Slughorn.

> "We are here to persuade an old colleague of mine to come out of retirement and back to Hogwarts."
>   <sub>*(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4, Horace Slughorn)*.</sub>

However, the presence of older teachers like McGonagall and Flitwick would seem to indicate that teachers can continue to a ripe old age if they want.

> " How long have you been teaching at Hogwarts?" Professor Umbridge asked.
>   "Thirty-nine years this December," said Professor McGonagall brusquely, snapping her bag shut.
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 15, The Hogwarts High Inquisitor)*.</sub>

This would likely be at the discretion of the headmaster, based on whether their teaching and intellect remained at a high standard. Although since Dumbledore is no spring chicken himself I think he'd be unlikely to *force* a teacher to retire if they wanted to stay on.

Comment: If that is the case, whole generations of kids would miss the opportunity to be teachers at Hogwarts. That's quite sad.

Comment: They'll get over it.

Comment: Did you ever get over it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall any mention of a professor being called too old to teach.

I don't think there's any maximum age, witches and wizards tend to live longer, and stay healthier for longer due to magical medicines and potions, so they stay active longer with whatever they're doing. Aberforth Dumbledore was 116 while running a bar, & Bathilda Bagshot  was at least 120.